# React Js : .map is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, axios

I have json array as below -

```
[{"sup_Id":6,"sup_ShortCode":"A"},{"sup_Id":7,"sup_ShortCode":"B"},{"sup_Id":8,"sup_ShortCode":"C"},{"sup_Id":1000,"sup_ShortCode":"D"}]
```

React component reading this array as -

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
function AllSuppliers() {
    const [suppliers, setstate] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        // GET request using axios inside useEffect React hook
        axios.get('http://localhost:62815/api/values/GetAllSuppliers')
            .then(x => setstate({suppliers:x.data}))
            .catch(error => {
                alert(error);
                
            });;
    }, []);
    return (
        <>
            <table style={{width: '50%'}}>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>
                    Supplier Id
                </th>
                <th>
                    Supplier Name
                </th>
                
                </tr>
                </thead>
                {
                   
                    suppliers.map((supplier)=>supplier)
                }
            </table>
        </>
    )
}

export default AllSuppliers
```

I am getting -

> TypeError: suppliers.map is not a function

error

I also tried with - `suppliers[0].map` since its an array. But this also did not worked.

Comment: Does you print the response data from the `GetAllSuppliers` request?

Comment: yes .. I am getting response data from GetAllSuppliers , I have made sure of that..also pasted part of response in question.

Comment: You should pass data as parameter in  `setstate` function instead of pass an object

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a JS array and not JSON as a response from the API? 
If it's JSON have you tried to parse your JSON data before setting it into the state?
`setstate(JSON.parse(x.data))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting your suppliers state to be an object in this line:

```
.then(x => setstate({suppliers:x.data}))
```

Instead, let the setstate handle the change of suppliers and only pass the variable like this:

```
.then(x => setstate(x.data))
```

assuming x.data is an array.

You can also change the following line `suppliers.map((supplier)=>supplier)` to `(suppliers || []).map((supplier)=>supplier)` this way in case x.data or suppliers get changed to null\undefined your app will not crash.

Also as mentioned above the usage of setstate is not recommended. I'd advise you read about this topic here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 1):

Use this way as you are using Hooks

```
setstate(x.data)
```

instead of this way which uses in class component

```
setstate({suppliers:x.data})
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the useState initialization as :

```
const [suppliers, setSuppliers] = useState([])
```

(It is more meaningful)

Also, Update the useEffect as :

```
useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:62815/api/values/GetAllSuppliers')
            .then(x => setSuppliers(x.data))
            .catch(error => {
                alert(error);
            });;
    }, []);
```

You need not set the state in an object when using React Hooks unlike normal class state.